# Dll is not getting uninstalled from GAC during uninstall only

Tags: dll, windows-installer, installshield, gac

I am copying a dll to GAC by specifying it in a component of one feature. 
I have installed my package by selecting that feature. The dll was copied to GAC. But when perform uninstall, that dll is still left over in GAC.

During modify, I found one strange thing. After installaing my package by selecting that feature, I clicked on modify, unchecked that feature and proceeded the installation.
At that time, the dll was uninstalled from GAC.

In both cases, the feature state is showing as 2.

I found below information in log file during uninstallation.

`MSI (s) (18:DC) [09:59:16:619]: Doing action: InstallValidate
MSI (s) (18:DC) [09:59:16:620]: Feature: MyFeature; Installed: Absent;   Request: Null;   Action: Null`

And during modify

`MSI (s) (18:DC) [09:59:16:619]: Doing action: InstallValidate
MSI (s) (A8:9C) [09:32:42:720]: Feature: MyFeature; Installed: Local;   Request: Absent;   Action: Absent`